# Laravel Eloquent - How to return a calculated value inside a scope query as a model column or collection property

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model, coordinates

I'm trying to get a list of users that are near the authenticated user and also return the distance between them using Laravel's Eloquent. I got it to work using raw SQL, but now I'm almost there making it work properly using mostly eloquent.

So, on the User model I have this method:

```
public function getUsersAround($coordinates, $radius = 5)
{
    return $this->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($coordinates, $radius) {
            $query->distance($coordinates, $radius);
        })->paginate(10);
}
```

Then on the Location model, I have the following scope:

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $coordinates, $radius)
{
    return $query
        ->join('profiles', 'profiles.id', '=', 'locations.profile_id')
        ->having('distance', '<', $radius)
        ->selectRaw("profile_id,
                 (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS($coordinates->latitude))
                       * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
                       * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS($coordinates->coordinates))
                       + SIN(RADIANS($coordinates->latitude))
                       * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance")
        ->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
}
```

So, all the users in the radius are being returned correctly, but I also want to add the calculated distance to each returned user.

What's strange is that if I `dd($query->distance($coordinates, $radius));` I see all the users + a new distance property on each user object (with the correct value), but if I just return the query and `dd(auth()->user()->getUsersAround($coordinates, $radius))` inside the controller, the distance property is not there anymore.

Is there a way to return the calculated distance inside the scope query and persist it on the Users object when returning the list of users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the distance in the results, you need the load the `location` relation with the `distance` attribute. Since you are already selecting the `distance` in the query scope on the Location model, you can achieve this quite easily:

```php
public function getUsersAround($coordinates, $radius = 5)
{
    return $this->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($coordinates, $radius) {
        $query->distance($coordinates, $radius);
    })->with([
        'location' => function ($query) use ($coordinates, $radius) {
            $query->select('locations.*')->distance($coordinates, $radius);
        }
    ])->paginate(10);
}
```

Notice the `with('location')`, which eager loads the Location model. I've added a `select('locations.*')` so that the `location` relation will have its own attributes, and the `distance($coordinates, $radius)` will also select the `profile_id` and the `distance` attributes.

So when you are calling `auth()->user()->getUsersAround($coordinates, $radius)` inside your controller, you can access the `distance` attribute with `$user->location->distance`:

```php
$users = auth()->user()->getUsersAround($coordinates, $radius);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $distance = $user->location->distance;
}
```

Comment: your solution works! however, i had to tweak it a little bit, as the `with()` method requires an associative array in order to constrain eager loads. thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your edit, indeed with needs an associative array syntax!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using ***get()* inside a scope** which is not correct. local scopes are intended to define common sets of constraints (like for filtering data).
check the documentation on [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) for more detail.

To add something to a select result, you can use [**addSelect**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries).

Comment: You're right about the get(), I forgot to remove it from the example. I put it there just to see the results when I used `dd($query->distance($coordinates, $radius));`

However, I couldn't find a way to use addSelect based on the code I already wrote. Could you please give me an example of how I can do it?

Comment: @DanielR. just follow Laravel's official documentation. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries)

Comment: unfortunately your solution doesn't work as I can't get the distance from inside the local scope and add it to the addSelect() as you suggested, but thanks for trying.